# onCreateView() in fragment never called?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a dual pane layout it works fine for tablet. But in case of phone Details fragment's onCreateView never getting called. Any reason?

```
       vehicleInfoFragment = new VehicleInfoDetailsFragment();
    Intent i = this.getIntent();
    index = i.getExtras().getInt(INDEX_LABEL, 0);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, vehicleInfoFragment).commit();
    vehicleInfoFragment.populateRouteDetails(index);
```

Comment: please post how you declare the vehicleInfoFragment

Comment: If i use the following it calls.. '@Override
 protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  
  super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
  vehicleInfoFragment.populateRouteDetails(index);
 }'